# ReactJS(jsx) Passing Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I was wondering why does the parameter (`a`) need to be passed with variables e.g `a.amount`, `a.date`. What is the process and reasoning behind this?

[image]

Comment: Paste your code. Not an image. It is difficult for users to recreate the issue

Comment: The props in React component is expected to be in form of key-value pair or a map object. If you want to directly access the title and date you can change the component signature like `function ExpenseItem({ title, date, amount })` and directly use title, date and amount from props

Comment: Because in your code `a` is the props object. You can reference the props ***from*** the props object, or destructure them in the function component signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general name for it "props" (in your component it is "a").

"Props" is an object that has all the properties passed to the component.

For example;

```
<ExampleComponent isEnabled={true} isClickable={false} />
```

Then you can access those properties in your component in two ways;

1: Get the prop variable and use it an object as you do in your example.
2: Destruct the object in your component to use as you want.

```
const ExampleComponent = ({isEnabled, isClickable}) => {
    return "<></>";
});
```

For more information:

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1):

React takes in a object name, to which you have given the name : `a`

If you have studied Objects in JavaScript, then to fetch the data, we use 'MyObj'.'key' to fetch the data, here is an example:

`const user = { first_name = 'Ayaan', last_name = 'Abbasi }`
so, to fetch your first name, we do the following:
`document.write(user.first_name)`

hence, in your example, your variable name is `a` and your data is the title, hence, to fetch your title, you can do `a.title` ,

for further information on components and props, please read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

you passed a prop in your component.

```
import HelloMessage from "./HelloMessage";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HelloMessage name={"tomnyson"} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function HelloMessage({name}) {
  return (
    <h1>{name}</h1>
  )
}
```

[image]

link source: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-tesla-3uk94?file=/src/App.js
look this document

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I was following a tutorial and they didn't quite explain it properly, but I've got it now thanks!